# client.(variable) variables in Discord.py Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am facing an issue while migrating my python code to discord.py.
The issue is, I don't know how to use client. variables in discord.py cogs like `client.sniped_messages = {}`...
It shows an error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arjun\Documents\Arjun\Python\discord.py\swayde\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "C:\Users\arjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\arjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 609, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.Utility' raised an error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Here's the code -

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import datetime

class Utility(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    self.client.sniped_messages = {}
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self,message):
        self.client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)

    @commands.command()
    async def snipe(self, ctx):
        try:
            contents, author, channel_name, time = self.client.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
        except:
            await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't find a message to snipe!")
            return

        embed = discord.Embed(description=contents, color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Utility(client))
```

Now, when I delete the variable `client.sniped_messages = {}`, The code runs perfectly.

Please tell me how I can resolve this issue and how to use `.client` variables in cogs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add your code? You simply haven't defined `self` (pretty sure you forgot to pass it to the method arguments)

Comment: Well then add the code, how are we supposed to help you otherwise? @TigerNinja

Comment: I did.
`class Utility(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client`

Comment: *code*
`def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Utility(client))`

Comment: **Not** in the comments, please edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent `self.client.sniped_messages = {}` so it's inside the `__init__` method

```py
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.client.sniped_messages = {}
```